# calculated column on jquery datatables after event occured

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'am new to the jquery datatables plugin and I'am looking for a way to calulate a column based on a event.
The event is a dropdown field that changed to another currency. If this event occurs, a column will be calculated. 
Columns:

```
Title | Cost - EUR | Cost - USD
```

Default the Cost - EUR is converted to USD. After the dropdown changed as example to GBP, the COST - USD header must be change to Cost - GBP ( thats easy ) and the values must be recalculated.

edit:

```
 <div>
    <table id="tableOne" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Periode</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Converted to:<div id="Converted Header"> USD</div></th>
                <th>Funding Source</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="filterth"></th>
                <th class="filterth"></th>
                <th class="filterth"></th>
                <th class="filterth"></th>
                <th class="filterth"></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

with this code I initialize my table with the first calculation:

```
$('#tableOne').DataTable({
                fixedColumns: true,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                dom: '<"toolbar">frt<"bottom"lip>',
                fnInitComplete: function () {
< SOME INTERNAL CODE >...
},
footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
 var api = this.api(), data;
 var intVal = function (i) {
     return typeof i === 'string' ?
        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
        typeof i === 'number' ?
        i : 0;
  };
filterTotalConverted = api
                        .column([4], { filter: 'applied' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);
                    //Write new Sum to column header
                    filterTotalWithSeperator = filterTotalConverted.toLocaleString('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })
     $('#costValueSumConverted').empty();
     $('#costValueSumConverted').append('Sum: ' + filterTotalWithSeperator);

"aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
{
                        "mData": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "PeriodDetails"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "CostValue",
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            var value = data.toLocaleString('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: base })
                            return value;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            var value = row.CostValue * currencyConvertValue;
                            value = value.toLocaleString('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: convertedTo })
                            return value;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "wb"
                    }
]
```

1. The first issue with this is that the column header sum function is not working on this calculated column
2. I don't have a idea how to recalculate the column after the dropdown changed...

Comment: Show us, what you've already tried. :) Best case: a runnable code snippet, which already initializes a table with data and some code of you trying to achieve the column changes.

Comment: See the linked questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548303/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-cell-in-datatables-net

Comment: added more information

Comment: Please add HTML and full Datatable initialization code.. We can't do much with these few info you provided..

Comment: added code to my description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example of how to update the column header and values when a drop down is changed.  In this example, I'm just multiplying the current cell value by a value based on what's selected in the drop down.  You'll need to use your conversion factors instead in order to change from one currency to the other.

**jQuery**

```
var dt = $('#example').DataTable({

});

$('#dd').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();

  //update column header
  $('.sSpecial').each(function() {
    $(this).text(" " + selected);
  });

  if (selected === "") return;

  //get 3rd column
  var column = dt.column(3);
  var sum = 0;

  //iterate over column data()
  $.each(column.data(), function(index, value) {
    var val = parseFloat(value);
    var factor = parseFloat(selected);

    //update the cell with the new value, and draw()
    dt.cell(index, 3).data(val * selected).draw();

    sum += (val * selected);
  });
//put sum in footer
$( column.footer() ).text(sum);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="dd">
<option value="">Select Something</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rendering engine</th>
      <th>Browser</th>
      <th>Platform(s)</th>
      <th>Engine version<span class="sSpecial"></span></th>
      <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td> 4</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/ssk43otw/49/